# No suitable driver found for jdbc: oracle: thin:@localhost:1521:orcl

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

**My JDK:**1.8.0.112

**My oracle:**11.2.0.2 express

**My IDE:**Intelij Idea 13

**My code:**

package model;
import java.sql.*;

public class PersonDA {

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc: oracle: thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","*****","********");
    Statement statement= connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet= statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Person");

    while (  resultSet.next()){

        System.out.println(resultSet.getString("ID"));
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString("name"));

    }
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

}

**Exception:**
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: **No suitable driver** found for jdbc: oracle: thin:@localhost:1521:orcl

```
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)

at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)

at model.PersonDA.main(PersonDA.java:8)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: How do you resolve missing dependencies? I think the oracle jar is missing in the classpath.

Comment: Why do you have spaces in your JDBC URL?

Answer (score 1):

Change your URL from:

```
"jdbc: oracle: thin:@//localhost:1521:orcl"
```

to this:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

The exception occurred because of wrong space between ':' and 'oracle' in code.and also  between ':' and 'thin'.